# Only some error messages show, others just give me a blank page

Tags: php, cakephp

Just like the title says. Some errors get displayed to the page, others simply prevent the page from loading properly. The Layout gets displayed but the body block becomes empty.

For example, I get a 500 with the message `call to member function allow() on a non object`. The only reason I can see this message is because I can check the variables list on DebugKit toolbar. Without the stacktrace I don't know how to localize this error.

Comment: Check if you loaded the model you are using to call allow() function.

Comment: that's not what I'm asking about though, I can't really keep working if I can't debug my code

Comment: I tend to put a 'die('i am here:'.__FILE__.__LINE__)'. Starting with the top level that i would expect to work i.e. controller then move it down the code until it stop appearing. It does not take long to find out where it goes wrong. Another way is to use the 'logger' to add messages to the log instead of the 'die...'.

Comment: Is there a better way? I know pretty much every other php mvc framework at least gives me a stacktrace.

Comment: This may be useful: **[book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html)**